# android EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS has wrong ui

Tags: android

problem desc:
    I filter out Intents with a specified apps list, everything is works fine, but the dialog of share showed is abnormal.
    The target Intent of createChooser showed with a newline, it should be at the end of the apps list, here is my screenshot and code.
Hope someone can help.

[image]

```
public void share(Context context, String title, String text, String url) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (resolveInfos == null) {
            return;
        }

        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ResolveInfo info : resolveInfos) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mSpecified.entrySet()) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(entry.getValue())) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text + url);
                    intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                    intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);

                    targetedShareIntents.add(intent);
                }
            }
        }

        if (targetedShareIntents.size() < SHARE_APP_COUNT) {
            boolean findExists = false;
            for (ResolveInfo info : resolveInfos) {

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mSpecified.entrySet()) {
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(entry.getValue())) {
                        findExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (findExists) {
                    findExists = false;
                    continue;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text + url);
                intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);

                targetedShareIntents.add(intent);
            }
        }

        Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(targetedShareIntents.size() - 1), title);
        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        context.startActivity(openInChooser);
```